# Are questions about translations in general on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, translations

This was prompted by this question: [Does a translation editor need to know the language of the source document?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8663/58)

---

Recently, a question was [asked](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8663/58) about the editing / translation process of a work in general - confirmed by the OP in [a comment](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8663/does-a-translation-editor-need-to-know-the-language-of-the-source-document#comment14835_8663) that they weren't restricting the question to *literary* translations.

Is this type of question actually on-topic here? This seems more like a question about the process of *creating* a work of literature, which seems like it would be more fitting on Writing.SE.

---

(Yes, I'm aware I answered the question. A quick check in chat seemed to indicate that there was precedent, so I answered it. However, I'd like to actually have a meta discussion about it.)

Comment: Is *this* question really about translations in general or the process of translation?

Comment: @muru - both; the creative part of a translation.

Comment: How different is https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/705/168 from this, then?

Comment: @muru - very. That's asking about dealing with questions about / related to translations of existing works. This is asking about questions related to translations not about existing, published works..

Comment: so not about translations in general, but unpublished translations?

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaning toward **No**. Just as general questions about how writers create new literary works are off-topic here, general questions about how translators do or should translate are also off-topic. Those questions are [better handled at writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info). Translation studies is [a vast field in itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_studies), and while it overlaps with literature, it is not a subset.

Questions about existing translations of literary works are fine. Questions specifically foregrounding the translation of those works are also fine, and that's why we have our [translation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag. That is to say, if a questions asks about any of these:

- [differences between two translations of the same work](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6725/289)
- [Whether a particular work has been translated into a given language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8557/289)
- [What the original language of a given work was](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8470/289)
- [What the original was of a given translation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16425/289)
- [Choices made by the translator](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15369/289)

... then the questions seem on-topic, as they are not about *creating* new translations. But other questions about translations seem out of scope for us:

- [Whether a translation into Language T from Language S should use a word that is a loanword from T to S, if the original text does not in fact use that word](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3964/289)
- [How to re-translate a book that has a bad translation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9577/289)
- [How to assess the quality of a translation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8565/289)

Although none of these have been closed here, all seem off-topic for us. The first two would probably be better asked at [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com). The last would generate only opinion-based answers. When reading poetry in translation, for example, some people might prefer a more literally accurate rendition even if it is in prose, while others might prefer a poetic recreation that takes liberties with the phrasing of the original.

Questions about [which is the best translation of a given work](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15056/289) also seem opinion-based. Even if the question defines "best" in a certain way, e.g., "easiest to read," what counts as easy to read is subjective.